# Server and client side encryption in S3 (EMR config)

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, emr

Quick & simple question, but couldn't find anything in the docs:

In my `emrfs-site.xml`, can I set both `fs.s3.enableServerSideEncryption` and `fs.s3.cse.enabled` to true? Will that provide double encryption, or it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, "Amazon S3 SSE and CSE are mutually exclusive; you can choose either but not both." per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-cluster-configuration-object-encryption.html

Comment: I was reading the very same doc to configure. Can't believe I missed that! Thanks.